# Perl: What does m/^.*\.(\d+)$/ mean?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a:

```
 my ($pid) = ($_ =~ m/^.*\.(\d+)$/);
```

What does $pid matches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not matching `$pid` here, but `$_` to the regex - `m/^.*\.(\d+)$/`.
The `$pid` will store the result of matching `$_` with the regex pattern.

Here's an explanation of regex pattern:

```
m/       # Delimiter
   ^     # Match beginning of string
   .*    # Match 0 or more repetition of any character except a newline
   \.    # Match a dot (.)
   (     # Start a capture group
     \d+ # Match 1 or more repetition of digits.
   )     # Close capture group
   $     # Match end of string
/
```

So, if the value in `$_` matches the above pattern, `$pid` will contain the value captured in first captured group, since you have got a parenthesis around `$pid`, so your matching operation will evaluate in list context.

Your matching is effectively the same as:

```
# Note you can remove the `m`, if you use `/` as delimiter.
my ($pid) = /^.*\.(\d+)$/
```

One more thing to notice is that, since you are doing nothing with the text matched at the beginning, you don't really need to match it. So, you can remove `.*` altogether, but in that case you have to remove the *caret (^)* from there. So, your regex now can be replaced with:

```
my $(pid) = /\.(\d+)$/
```

Comment: Actually, `$pid` will contain the first capture group, since the parens around `$pid` make this a list assignment, and so the `=~` is evaluated in list context.

Comment: @llmari. OOPs. Missed that.

Comment: To pick a few more nits, "sentence" above should be "string", and `.` will match any character _except_ a newline (since the `/s` switch is not used). That one's probably a bug, though. Assuming that it is, the whole thing could be written more compactly as `my ($pid) = ($_ =~ /\.(\d+)$/);`, or even just `my ($pid) = /\.(\d+)$/;`. Also, `$` can also match the position just before a newline at the end of the string.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen. Well, let me re-structure my answer. :)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen. Refactored my answer now. :) As for your last statement, `$` always matches the position just before the newline at the end of the string, unless we are talking about multiline matching right?

Comment: `$` matches either the actual end of the string, or, if the string ends in a newline,  just before it. Unless the `/m` switch is used, in which case it indeed also matches just before _any_ newline, regardless of their position in the string.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen. Yeah that's what I said. `/m` switch is used to enable `multi-line` matching.

Comment: @Rohit Jain Thanks! and, mm, maybe /\.(\d+)$/ is a bit too much?
this is the context:

   for (glob ".....*") {
        my ($pid) = ($_ =~ m/^.*\.(\d+)$/);
        next unless is_running($pid);
        open(my $file, "<", $_) or croak "can't open $_: $!";
        .....